# Redux Dispatch with combineReducers and createSlice

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, frontend, redux-toolkit

I have some sets of checkbox with actions on checking and unchecking a box from some options. However when I dispatch an action nothing happens. Both the payload and type seem valid to me.

Here is the checkbox set code.

```js
function CheckboxOptions(props:NamedOptions<any>): JSX.Element {
  function handleCheckboxChange(e, index:number) {
    ...
    if(isChecked){
      const actionName = "CHECK_" + itemName; 
      createStudyStore.dispatch({type: actionName, payload:index});
    }
    else{
      const actionName = "UNCHECK_" + itemName; 
      createStudyStore.dispatch({type: actionName, payload:index});
    }
  }

  
  let checkboxes = props.options.map((option, i)=>{
    ...
    return (<Grid>
        <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox onChange={(e)=>handleCheckboxChange(e,i)}/>} label={optionTxt}/>
      </Grid>
    );
  });
  return <>
    {checkboxes}
  </>;
};
```

The type and the payload are correct, however I am not getting the dispatch to do anything.

The following is my reducer factory as I have many checkboxes

```js
function createNamedOptionsReducerWithNamedType(name=""){
    return function namedOptionReducer(state:NamedOptions<any>, action:PayloadAction<number>): NamedOptions<any>{
        switch (action.type){
            case "CHECK_${name}":
                state.value[action.payload] = true;
                return state;
            case "UNCHECK_${name}":
                state.value[action.payload] = false;
                return state;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
}
```

A slice is created as follows

```js
const open_variables_slice = createSlice({
    name: "open_variables",
    initialState: initial_form.open_variables,
    reducers: getReducers(open_variable_keys, initial_form.open_variables) 
})
```

getReducers returns a map of reducers, one for each checkbox set and calls createNamedOptionsReducerWithNamedType internally.

My root reducer is defined as follows and associated with my store.

```js
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    open_variables : open_variables_slice.reducer,
    independent_variables : independent_variables_slice.reducer,
    ladder_variables : ladder_variables_slice.reducer,
})

export const createStudyStore = configureStore({reducer: rootReducer});
```

I do not understand how to go about debugging this. I have printed the action type and payload and it matches the supposedly valid action types that get printed out from me printing in the reducer factory. Perhaps createSlice requires I call my dispatches with action types created by createAction? Or maybe rootReducer somehow namespaces my reducers? Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I found out about redux devTools and used it. It looks like my actions show up in the action tab... state does not change however.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple problems in your code.

By far the biggest one is that you are *mutating* state in your reducer, and you must *never* do that with Redux:

```
                state.value[action.payload] = true;
```

(*If* that is ultimately getting used inside of `createSlice`, then that line is okay.  But the layers of wrapping and reducer generation you're using make it hard to tell what you're actually doing.)

Another issue is that it looks like you are directly importing *a* Redux store into the component ( `createStudyStore.dispatch()` ), and the fact that you have it named that way suggests there could be *multiple* Redux stores in this app.  Those are also things you must not do with Redux.

I don't actually see any use of React-Redux in your code, such as `useSelector` .  You may just have omitted that from the snippets you posted, but if you aren't using it, the UI definitely won't update.

I'd strongly recommend going through the "Redux Essentials" tutorial in our core docs:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: Thanks for responding! Yeah redux is a little hard to make a post about minimally when I'm new to it as there's a lot of moving parts and I don't know what could be happening. The mutation is inside createSlice so it should be using immer. I only have one store per page and right now this is the only page, so I don't believe that is an issue.

Comment: I didn't see useSelector or useDispatch in the examples, I'll try them out. I think I was looking at old examples without toolkit. Thanks.

Comment: to be clear, `useSelector` and `useDispatch` are part of React-Redux, which you would be using regardless of whether you're writing the Redux _logic_ old-style by hand, or writing the logic with Redux Toolkit: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react